# Install Node.js v16 alongside an ASP.NET Core Angular application within a Docker Alpine image

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, alpine-linux

I'm currently working on containerizing an ASP.NET Core Angular app using an Alpine image.

The problem is that running the following dockerfile i got the errors
 `line 2: npm: not found` and `The command "npm install" exited with code 127`.

Curious fact: when using the approach below, everythink was fine and working

```
ENV NODE_VERSION=16.13.1
RUN curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://unofficial-builds.nodejs.org/download/release/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64-musl.tar.xz"; \
  tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64-musl.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner \
  && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs;
  
FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish 'MyApp.API.csproj' -c Release -o /app/publish --no-restore
```

```yaml
FROM node:16-alpine AS node_builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY MyApp/ClientApp/package*.json ./
RUN npm install --force

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyApp.Models ./MyApp.Models
COPY MyApp.Service ./MyApp.Service
COPY MyApp.Repository ./MyApp.Repository
COPY MyApp./MyApp

WORKDIR /src/MyApp
RUN dotnet restore 'MyApp.API.csproj'

RUN dotnet build 'MyApp.API.csproj' --disable-parallel -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
COPY --from=node_builder /app/dist /app/dist
RUN dotnet publish 'MyApp.API.csproj' -c Release -o /app/publish --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine AS final
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
RUN apk add --no-cache \
  icu-data-full \
  icu-libs

COPY --from=publish /app/publish/ /app/

EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.API.dll"]
```

The issue I'm facing is that I require Node.js in the publish stage because the dotnet publish command automatically runs npm install. Although I understand that I need to copy Node.js dependencies into the publish stage, I've been encountering errors for hours without success.

Note: I can't use `RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs=16 npm` to download Node.js from Alpine packages because version 16 is not available

#### Solution

I solved the issue the next day I posted this question. This is the solution:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/ nodejs=16.20.2-r0

RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/ npm=7.17.0-r0
```

The error I was facing was because `npm` wasn't being installed and `node` was being downloaded incorrectly. The above solution shows how to fix the error.

Comment: Why do you need Node version 16? The .NET build process isn't that picky with what version is used, AFAIK. 20 should work. 16 is EOL and no longer maintained.

Comment: I don't think nodejs version is the problem here. I could download any version that I'd sill get the same error `npm: not found` and `The command "npm install" exited with code 127`. It seems that when running `dotnet publish` npm is not available

Comment: If node version isn't the issue, then use `RUN apk add --no-cache nodejs npm` to install version 20.